# Using Newton Binomials and Combinatorics to reach this big O result?

Tags: combinatorics, computational-complexity, binomial-theorem

I'm trying to understand this theorem proof:

Theorem. Given a set of n agents, the dynamic programming algorithm, DP, computes an optimal coalition structure in $O(3^n)$ time.

[Proof of theorem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oplBq.png)

How can I connect the concepts to find $O(3^n)$?
You don't need to understand the context to answer the question, I just need someone who knows how to extract the big O notation from sum series.

And why a = 2, and b = 1?

Full article: http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/people/michael.wooldridge/pubs/aij2015a.pdf

Comment: $a = 2$, and $b = 1$ so that you get $3^{n}$ from the binomial theorem, but you must already know this :)

Comment: Yes, if you develop the right side of equation to reach $3^n$ too, it would be nice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plug $a=2,b=1$ in the Binomial formula:

$$(2+1)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom nk 2^k1^{n-1},$$

$$3^n=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom nk 2^k.$$

Comment: You can see that $\sum^{n}_{k = 0} \binon{n}{k}2^k$ is similar to $\sum^{n}_{s = 1} \binon{n}{s}2^{s - 1}$, but how the two things can be connected theoretically?

Comment: @Ráfagan Come on, this is trivial.

Comment: Could you develop the right side of equation to get $3^n$ too?

Comment: @Ráfagan What do you mean ? It's in front of your eyes.

Comment: $3^n = \sum^{n}_{k=0} \binom{n}{k}2^k \implies ... \text{ } \therefore 3^n = 3^n$

Comment: @Ráfagan Yet more obscure. Explain in words.